# archlinux aif command not found

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I started Archlinux after grub and I see a

```
[root@archiso ˜]#
```

command bash. The installation guide tells me to either type

```
/arch/setup
```

or

```
aif -p interactive
```

to start the interactive installation routine with the Archlinux installation framework. However the bash console tells me "aif: command not found" (I tried if even only "aif" works). Am I at the wrong place? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: What's a newbie doing with arch linux :O

Comment: learning the hard way. To be honest, I`m overwhelmed by it but I have a 1000+ pages linux opus and a lot of motivation to compensate;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AIF, the Arch Installer Framework, has been removed from the new ISOs. There will be a formal announcement in the next couple of days. For the moment, you can read the details [on the mailing list](http://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2012-July/023238.html).

You can now use the [Arch Install Scripts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Install_Scripts) as described on the wiki.

There is also [this thread on the Arch boards](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1131593) which has some more detail about the reasons behind the switch.

Essentially, the developer [has resigned](http://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2012-July/023227.html) and there is a tremendous amount of work required to get the project back up and running and none of the current developers is interested in picking it up, so they have opted for a simpler, more manageable tool.

#### Edit

The official announcement has been posted: http://www.archlinux.org/news/install-media-20120715-released/